# find value in complex object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, google-publisher-tag

Basically I have a complex object that retrieves the GPT API (google publisher tag) with this function:

```
googletag.pubads().getSlots();
```

The object value is something like this:
[image]

I need to know if there is a way to compare the value of each property with an X value without getting a problem of recursivity (because the object is huge and i need to to that validation several times)
Also, I tried to convert that object into a JSON with JSON.stringify(), and then tried to get the value with a regex, faster, but with this option, I have the problem with Cyclic Object Value.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you provide the code? Not the screenshot.

Comment: @Nitheesh If they were able to serialize the object they wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js to remove cycles, then use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You don't know how to make a loop?

Comment: @PHPglue Exactly. my problem is that I don't know how to make a loop that works with this, because as I said in my post, with a normal loop you have a recursivity problem.

Comment: @Nitheesh There is no code, is just a HUGE javascript complex object, that and I need to find a value from there and iterate it several times, and I don't want the recursivity problem, that's why I need some help

Answer (score 0):

it's more simple. try it to convert it into an array and later use a filter for comparative with your value.

```
var objGoogle = {};
var arrayObjectGoogle = [objGoogle];
var filter = arrayObjectGoogle.filter(function(obj){
  obj.yourAttr == yourValue;  });
```

this will give you a second array with the values found it. later, index the array for pick up the value do you need.